# Can't fix Arch Linux after breaking Python through pip

Tags: arch-linux

**UPDATED today 2022Nov16-1520GTM**

After messing up installing python via pip on my pinebook pro it wasn’t possible to update and upgrade the system anymore.
Suggested solution was:

delete the Python stuff installed via pip,

and run:

```
sudo pacman -S manjaro-system
sudo pacman -Syu --overwrite "*"
```

It didn't work smoothly. Problems with:

```
:: Replace breath2-icon-themes with community/plasma5-themes-breath? [Y/n] y
...
:: Replace plasma5-themes-breath2 with community/plasma5-themes-breath? [Y/n] y
:: Replace sddm-breath2-theme with community/sddm-breath-theme? [Y/n] y
```

Then I tried:

```
...
:: Replace breath2-icon-themes with community/plasma5-themes-breath? [Y/n] n
...
:: Replace plasma5-themes-breath2 with community/plasma5-themes-breath? [Y/n] n
:: Replace sddm-breath2-theme with community/sddm-breath-theme? [Y/n] n
```

Done! But afterwards, there were failed systemd units:

```
journalctl -p 3 -b
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: debugfs: File ':interrupt-controller@fee00000' in directory 'domains' already present!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: OF: graph: no port node found in /i2c@ff3d0000/fusb30x@22
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: rockchip-pcie f8000000.pcie: PCIe link training gen1 timeout!
Oct 25 13:44:17 lxm kernel: mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm kernel: rockchip-dp ff970000.edp: no DP phy configured
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[303]: event6: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x70066, and key code 142: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[303]: event6: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a5, and key code 224: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[303]: event6: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a6, and key code 225: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[308]: event4: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x70066, and key code 142: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[308]: event4: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a5, and key code 224: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[308]: event4: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a6, and key code 225: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[301]: event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x70066, and key code 142: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[301]: event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a5, and key code 224: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[301]: event7: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a6, and key code 225: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[319]: event8: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x70066, and key code 142: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[319]: event8: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a5, and key code 224: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[319]: event8: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a6, and key code 225: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[306]: event5: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x70066, and key code 142: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[306]: event5: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a5, and key code 224: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:39 lxm systemd-udevd[306]: event5: Failed to call EVIOCSKEYCODE with scan code 0x700a6, and key code 225: Invalid argument
Nov 16 10:09:41 lxm bluetoothd[412]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Nov 16 10:09:41 lxm systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Nov 16 10:13:16 lxm pulseaudio[853]: module-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.
Nov 16 11:14:33 lxm kernel: .ready
Nov 16 15:10:39 lxm kernel: clk_spi1 already disabled
Nov 16 15:10:39 lxm kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep zram r8153_ecm cdc_ether usbnet uvcvideo r8152 mii snd_soc_simple_amplifier joydev videobuf2_vmalloc hci_uart panfrost>
Nov 16 15:10:39 lxm kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 5853 Comm: systemd-sleep Tainted: G         C         6.0.7-2-MANJARO-ARM #1
```

**How to get rid of the above mentioned issues and get the system running smoothly?**

**Should I reinstall Manjaro from the scratch?**

Or:

**Should I install Debian ARM or Ubuntu ARM?**

Comment: With this kind of system-wide problem, I suggest to reinstall the whole distribution.
I don't understand when you say "*installing python via pip*", as python is already installed on all Linux distributions...

Comment: Actually I tried to install a higher version through “pip”… Bad move. 
After searching the Net I understood, that I shouldn’t use “pip”. 
Then I tried to remove the 2 installations did using “pip”. It didn’t work. 
Now I’m looking forward to understand how to reinstall ARCH Majaro (I’m comfortable with Debian or a compatible Ubuntu distro. But,  it seems to be difficult to install those distros on the PineBook Pro). 
Anyway I’m not sure how to install ARCH Majaro via an image on an USB.
I’m still looking for an solution…

Comment: Yep, your system seems to be really broken, I highly recommend you to reinstall, because even if you more or less solve the problem now, the risk is to encounter some weird behaviours later.